# VisualStudio | Summary - IntelliSense custom tag

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, documentation, summary

Is there a way to add custom tags for the `summary` in `VisualStudio 2017` to see them in the `IntelliSense`?
I have an object `HtReturnStatus` which contains a `HtErrorCode`. There are around ~100 `HtErrorCode` in our library. So it would be an improovement for us if it would be possible to declare the error codes the method could return.

(If needed, `ReSharper` is available)

Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments

```
public class Foo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method returns error codes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <ErrorCodes>
    /// <see cref="HtErrorCode.USER_WrongCredentials"/> / <see cref="HtErrorCode.USER_UserNotFound"/>
    /// </ErrorCodes>
    public static HtReturnStatus Login()
    {
        return HtReturnStatus.Failed(HtErrorCode.USER_WrongCredentials);
    }
}
```

---

**Hint**
If you want to add custom tags in your XML documentation file, have a look at the solution from `Peter Macej` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49757547/6229375)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the info about the error codes to be visible in IntelliSense or in generated documentation? If in IntelliSense, you should put it in some existing top level XML doc tag. The best seems <returns> to me. For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method returns error codes.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// The <see cref="HtErrorCode"/> object with one of the following error codes:
/// <see cref="HtErrorCode.USER_WrongCredentials"/> or <see cref="HtErrorCode.USER_UserNotFound"/>.
/// </returns>
```

If that info is longer, I would put it inside <remarks> tag.

If you really want a separate top-level block as in your example, this can be done. But it will not be shown in Intellisense, only in generated documentation. 
I don't know how about other tools, but our [VSdocman](https://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) (I'm the developer of it) supports exactly such [custom tags](https://www.helixoft.com/files/vsdocman/help/commentopt_3.html).

Comment: Primary I need it in IntelliSense. So `VSdocman` is only for documentation?

Comment: VSdocman can generate documentation and edit the XML comments (it has WYSIWYG comment editor). But it doen't extend built-in IntelliSense.

Comment: The custom tags link is broken.

Comment: @Marcel: The link is fixed now.